# Redirect to two ports using Nginx

Tags: nginx, devops

I have two angular apps running on different ports. I need to access app1 when the user calls https://url and app2 when the user calls https://url/admin. I tried adding location block to the Nginx config as below but the request is directed to app1 with the /admin added.

```
server {
#        listen 80 default_server;
#        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        listen 443 ssl;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name fr.techolution.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/url_com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myserver.key;
location / {
 proxy_pass http://192.168.2.81:8083;
}
location  /admin/ {
 proxy_pass http://192.168.2.81:4200;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both requests https://url and https://url/admin will be proceeds in the location:

```
location / {
 proxy_pass http://192.168.2.81:8083;
}
```

Looks like you should remove slash from your second location:

```
location  /admin {
 proxy_pass http://192.168.2.81:4200;
}
```

Comment: It sounds impossible ). Anyway confirm that please:
All requests should be proceeded by `http://192.168.2.81:8083`. Requests to `/admin` or `/admin/something` should be proceeded by `http://192.168.2.81:4200`